# Datalog Rule taking forever to compute

Tags: sparql, rdf, datalog, rdfox

I'm using RDFox v3 and when I import the following rule it takes a long time to run. My datastore has CRM information and I'm trying to classify their origins using rules.

```
[ ?customer, :referral, "true"] :-  [ ?customer, :has, ?referralLink] .
```

I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This suggests you have a lot of `:has` relationships in your data. If this is the case the variables you have listed as `?customer` and `?referralLink` are matching on everything that is related by `:has`. This is happening regardless of whether they are a customer or not and that is what I suggest may be taking the time.

If `?customer` and `?referralLink` have types you might want to specify this in your rule. For example supposing they are of type `:CustomerType` and `:ReferralLinkType` then your rule will become:

```
[ ?customer, :referral, "true"] :- 
   [ ?customer, :has, ?referralLink] ,
   [ ?customer, a, :CustomerType] ,
   [ ?referralLink, a, :ReferralLinkType] .
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thank you Peter, this worked and RDFox materialised the rule in 125ms!